# Using Jasper Reports 6.x to print to Thermal Printer Tape Printer

Tags: jasper-reports

I am looking for an example of how to print to a thermal printer using Jasper Reports.  This is an accounting solution, which prints a "Balance" tape, therefore I am not sure how long the paper will be.  I need to print this to a networked printer.  I am unsure on how to set up the template and can't find an example.

This is what I am looking to do.

[image]

I was hoping someone has solved this using Jasper Reports, and could point me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a text field which will contain your list of amounts
2. Set the property `Stretch with overflow` to `true` this will let the field grow.